# Not only X but also Y are (is?)

Tags: grammar, verbs, grammatical-number, negation

At first glance, sentence 1 below seems more correct because there are two subjects. However, something seems more natural about sentence 2. Maybe there is something abbreviated, elliptical, or adverbial in sentence 2.

In sentences of this structure, should the verb be singular or plural?

> 1. Not only a book, but also a pencil are on the table
> 2. Not only a book, but also a pencil is on the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct word should be ***is***.

You wouldn't normally say "a book are on the table" or "a pencil are on the table". Since you did not make a list of nouns or use any plural nouns, the verb should remain singular.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
So the following would also be singular?

"A book, and also a pencil, is on the table."
"John, and also Bob, is in the room." 

Seems like those cases would require “are”?

Comment: Yes, they both would use "are", as you made a list of nouns (book and pencil, John and Bob).

Comment: Have you a recognised reference analysing the focus associated with 'A and B', 'A, and also B', 'A, in addition to B', 'not only A but also B' etc constructions?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second question, you have now changed the focus from singular to plural.

In your first example it was "Not only X, but also a Y is on the table." The focus is on Y.
But in your second example it is "An X, and also a Y, are on the table." The focus is on X+Y.

So yes, in that situation, "are" is the correct word to use.

Comment: Have you a recognised reference analysing the focus associated with 'A and B', 'A, and also B', 'A, in addition to B', 'not only A but also B' etc constructions?

Answer (score 0):

Since "not only...but also" is a substitute for "and," the correct answer is that the verb is plural.  Grammar doesn't necessarily care that one structure sounds more normal than another but that one or the other or both are correct.

Comment: The answer up-voted four times and accepted by the OP is correct. Yours is wrong. Welcome to EL&U.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to "an X, and also a Y, are on the table," in this case, AND ALSO set off by commas is more like AS WELL AS, in which case, the singular verb would be correct: "an X, as well as a Y, is on the table. This is definitely a controversial issue! No majority here!